# Deleted question following an answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Well... just now, it is a bit irritating to tell the truth... but maybe that's life!

I just spent around an hour to answer a question and following that the question has been deleted.

Was my answer bad, or any other reasons? Understanding the cause is the main point to me.

What are your experiences about it?

The dead link: [Parenting mesh with armature deformation problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74072/parenting-mesh-with-armature-deformation-problem/74129#74129)

Comment: Just FYI that is not a dead link. any user with 10,000 or more rep can still see deleted posts.

Comment: @David, yes I know. For my information is there anything in my answer that leads to something bad for the OP (my way of writing or other)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why the OP deleted that question. There were no down votes, nasty comments, or anything that would make them want to delete it. (Maybe they just realized some stupid mistake.)

The question was deleted by the OP at 2017-02-21 08:43:01Z, your answer was posted at 2017-02-21 08:03:49Z some 40 minutes before the question was deleted.

In those 40 minutes, did the OP read you posts? I have no idea (my guess would be that he did see it).

This has nothing to do with you, or your answer. It looks like a good answer.
For whatever reason, the OP just deleted the question.

I will talk with [Tak](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2517/tak), explain that deleting posts is **not helpful** (in many ways), and ask why he deleted this one.

One way or another, I expect this post to be undeleted.

Comment: Thanks David for the answer. Don't spend too much time about that. Yes as I said, this is a bit frustrating, but not the end of the world. I was in hope to give some general indications (as far I am able to do), so I hoped it could be useful for 'many'. But again, I was much worried about something like 'my way of writing is not good' or something like that I may need to change myself

Comment: FYI I have talk to Tak on chat. All is OK... thanks David